# Type hierarchy only from JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse I often like to find more specific subclasses of an `Exception` - for example I open a type hierarchy of `IOException` or `IllegalArgumentException`.

What I see is a full hierarchy of the

- JDK
- Frameworks
- Libraries that are indirectly used.

I have to decide, what exception may match better. Very often I find an exception that fit my needs, but is not part of the JDK.

Question:

*Can i reduce the Hierarchy to JDK Libraries or a package only?*

Comment: Created FR https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444815

Comment: There already exists a feature request for [type hierarchy filters](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40630). Actually I guess this feature was forgotten/removed because the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-views-filtering.htm) claims that filters should already exist: `Several Java views (e.g. Outline, Type Hierarchy, Members) offer filtering of members `...

Comment: As a workaround you can also use the `Java search` to search for `Implementors` of `java.io.IOException` and limit the search to just the `JRE libraries`. But I think this will only show you *direct* subclasses of IOException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the Type Hierarchy can only be limited to projects (including their dependencies) from selected Working Sets.

Hence, the only workaround that comes to my mind is to create a Java project that serves as a *filter* and then create and select a Working Set that just contains this project.

Comment: This is a workaround that is **better that the direct way** because: My next question would have been: how to reduce them to compatibility for JDK5. **FYI** i called the project `compatibility-jdk5`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to see only JDK exception types:

Open the "Quick Type Hierarchy" (CTRL - T on the class name) and use the name filter.
Then type `*java.` and only exceptions of the java package will be shown.

Comment: You are right, I edited the post. It is working if you type ``*.java.`` instead of ``java.``.
And yes, I had written in the post only exceptions in packages which begin with ``java`` will be found. However, this should apply to most JDK exceptions.